# MVVM Set paramenter in xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created a `LoginDialog` and `UserControl`. If the Login Data in the `Dialog` are correct, the `user control` will open. Depends on the user which is logging in, there will be shown a picture and some data. For that i have the picture ID.

.xaml.cs

```
public Picture()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PictureViewModel();
    }
```

MainViewModel

```
private void LoadPictureViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = new PictureViewModel(ID);
    }
```

PictureViewModel

```
public PictureViewModel(int ID)
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
```

I have a null reference exception at my xaml.cs and I don't know, how to get the ID to the DataContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception occurs because you did not define a constructor without parameter for `PictureViewModel`. A better approach could be:

1. Create your `user control` when you have an id
2. use dependency injection instead